# Can´t update apps through mobile data.

Tags: samsung

Just restored to factory defaults and I can´t seem to update any app through mobile data, it needs wifi. Im on a Samsung Galaxy S5 android version 5.0

Answer (score -1):

Open Play Store, go to settings, Auto Update APPS, Untick OVER WIFI ONLY, select Auto Update apps at any time.

Comment: I set it at Do-not auto update apps because I hate auto updates. Then I found out there was a problem with my service provider.
Thanks though.